# SELECT query String contains '%' character

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

The requirement is to query for all the strings which contains '%' character in it. Example : "John%", "Jac%ob"

As '%' itself is a wildcard character, How to query for this??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Two basic ways to escape strings in SQL `LIKE` statements. Square brackets (e.g. `LIKE '%[%]%'`) and with the word ESCAPE (e.g. `LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\'`).

Comment: Is this in MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

When using LIKE with wildcards such as % you can escape the wildcard character with a \

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourstring LIKE '%John\%%' ESCAPE '\';
```

Or:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourstring LIKE '%Jac\%ob%' ESCAPE '\';
```

Also notice that they use single quotes for containing the strings, rather than double quotes.

Thanks to ZLK and blendenzo for clarification in the comments below.

Comment: You seem to have misread the question. I do not think they were asking how to use wildcards. They want to know how to look for strings which actually contain the % character.

Comment: @blendenzo - you're right, I did misread it. I've updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: This still will not work without the keyword `ESCAPE`. See my comment, for example. Also he's just looking for strings that contain percent signs, not those specific strings.

Comment: @ZLK it will work without the `escape` keyword as long as NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES is not enabled.

Comment: @blendenzo Indeed, for MySQL. In SQL server, it will not work without escape. There is no NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES option (unless it's in a newer version I'm not aware of). Question should probably be tagged properly to avoid confusion.